# Не полные данные в терминале

Tags: массивы, node.js, объекты, консоль, webstorm

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы в терминале выводились все данные, которые я пытаюсь вывести, а не пряталась часть из них в [Array], или [Object].

Например на скриншоте мы видим обрезанные данные (я так понял, чтобы не захламлять консоль). И я хочу чтобы сразу в выводе были раскрыты все [Array] и [Object], а не чтобы мне приходилось делать это в коде.

[image: 1]

Спасибо)

Comment: Вместо `console.log(data); ` попробуйте `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable));`

Comment: @Andrew Тогда я получу данные в одну строчку и прочитать это будет не возможно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При отладке кода в WebStorm объекты и массивы показываются в виде дерева в **Debugger Console**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

см. https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/03/webstorm-2019-1-eap-6/, *New Debugger Console*

Comment: Я пробовал использовать дебаггер, но в Console я получаю те-же данные, а в Debugger Console: "result > Object" и всё.

Comment: а какую версию IDE вы используете?

Comment: Последнюю стабильную. Регулярно обновляюсь до новой версии.

Comment: у меня это выглядит как на картинке в ответе (обновила картинку)